# How to insert SELECT LISTAGG values to varchar variable

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, sql-function, listagg

I am writing an Oracle user defined function. How can I insert listtagg values Pears, Oranges, Bananas, Apples into a variable products and return in function.

```
products VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
SELECT LISTAGG(product_name, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY product_name DESC) "Product_Listing"
FROM products;
RETURN products;
```

Comment: You are just few lines away from your working code. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply create a **function**, declare a string type **variable**, assign the values of **LISTAGG** to the variable, and return it.

For example,

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE
  2    FUNCTION func
  3      RETURN VARCHAR2
  4    IS
  5      str VARCHAR2(200);
  6    BEGIN
  7      SELECT LISTAGG(ename, ',') WITHIN GROUP (
  8      ORDER BY ename)
  9      INTO str
 10      FROM emp
 11      WHERE deptno = 10
 12      GROUP BY deptno;
 13      RETURN str;
 14    END;
 15    /

Function created.

SQL> select func from dual;

FUNC
--------------------------------------------------
CLARK,KING,MILLER

SQL>
```

Comment: Please increase length of string variable up to 4000 -> str VARCHAR2(4000);
Otherwise it will throw an exception if result is longer than 200.

Comment: @Rusty, it was just an example. It is OP who needs to decide that. If you have got an issue with that, then I would like to share a new 12c feature with you. You can now have 33767 bytes for VARCHAR type now in 12c.

Comment: Yup, it's a typo. I mean 32767. Thanks for pointing it, sometimes my fingers beat my brain :-)